# Does .prop behave differently for radio buttons?

Tags: jquery

When I tried to make [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mG8g/1/) work with radio buttons, I couldn't make it work. After reading several answers, I realize that I must be missing something very obvious. I'm trying to make it so that when I click the radio `Others`, it should enable a input form. I read somewhere that disabling the input form rules over `required`, which is perfect for what I'm trying to do; also the reason why I'm not trying to simply show/hide. I'm confused as to why the selection is not happening properly. It [clearly works for checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/3mG8g/1/). This is the snippet:

```js
$('#ctypeother').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#ctypeotherwhat').prop('readonly', true);
    $('#ctypeotherwhat').prop('disabled', false);
    //alert('checked');
  } else {
    $('#ctypeotherwhat').prop('readonly', true);
    $('#ctypeotherwhat').prop('disabled', true);
    //alert('not checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="A" /><label>A </label>
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="B" /><label>B </label>
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="C" /><label>C </label>
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="D" id="ctypeother" />
<label>Other </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ctypeother" id="ctypeotherwhat" placeholder="Please Specify" />
```

Comment: i suggest use change event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not-checked event is not being triggered correctly. Instead, use this:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
  if ($("#ctypeother").is(':checked')) {
    $('#ctypeotherwhat').prop('disabled',false);
  } else {
    $('#ctypeotherwhat').prop('disabled',true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="A" /><label>A </label>
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="B" /><label>B </label>
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="C" /><label>C </label>
<input type="radio" name="ctype" value="D" id="ctypeother" />
<label>Other </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ctypeother" id="ctypeotherwhat" placeholder="Please Specify"/>
```

Comment: perfect! can you tell me how I can find out which part of my trigger isn't working(for future reference)? or is it something you get with practice?

Comment: The `click` event isn't triggered when you click on the other 3 options. When you click it, it's always checked (because you just clicked it!).